# How to show FlashMessage in TYPO3 extension

Tags: php, typo3

I am searching a way to show FlashMessage when user added wrong input. This piece of code is not working. thanks.

```
$t3type = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::NOTICE;
$header = "Notice";
$mes = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::class,
            $message,
            $header, 
            $t3type, 
            true);
```

Comment: Where you add this code?

Comment: well it is in Class inside plugin which validates api key

Comment: Did you check this? - https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/10-template-creation-by-example.html?highlight=flash#setting-up-the-html-basic-framework

Comment: ok thanks for the link

Comment: Did this get resolved? It might make a difference to know where you are creating the flash message (in your Controller / with Fluid), in a CommandController, Hook etc.

Comment: There is another recent question about FlashMessages here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590844/displaying-a-flash-message-in-the-backend-using-a-hook-doesnt-work-somehow/47612206

Answer (score 2):

Try this TYPO3 Default function,

```
$this->addFlashMessage(
    'Your message!',
    'Description or something else..',
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::WARNING
);
```

Hope this will work for you! Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Add this in controller function

```
$this->addFlashMessage(
    $messageBody = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('LLL:EXT:yourextkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:error_body', 'yourextkey'),
    $messageTitle = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('LLL:EXT: yourextkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:error_title', 'yourextkey'),
    $severity = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR,
    $storeInSession = TRUE
);
```

and in fluid template add

```
<f:flashMessages />
```

More can be found in TYPO3 Core API documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FlashMessages/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add flashMessage like below.

```
$flashMessageTitle = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate(
    'flashmessage_title_done',
    $this->extensionName
);
$flashMessageBody = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate(
    'flashmessage_description',
    $this->extensionName
);
$this->addFlashMessage(
    $flashMessageBody,
    $flashMessageTitle,
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::NOTICE,
    true
);
```