# Displaying a flash message in the Backend using a hook doesn't work somehow

Tags: typo3

Basically: I want to display a flash message in the BE whenever the user enters a value that is not a valid IPv4. I want to do this in a hook, but just using the code from the Typo3 documentation for flash messages doesn't work there seems to be a major missunderstanding on my side maybe. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

namespace Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Hook;

class EvalHook {
function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$pObj) {

if (!filter_var($fieldArray[IPv4], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){

//here i want to put the flash message code

}
}
}
?>
```

Using the code from the documentation here:

```
$message = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::class,
   'My message text',
   'Message Header', // [optional] the header
   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::WARNING, // [optional] the severity defaults to \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::OK
   true // [optional] whether the message should be stored in the session or only in the \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageQueue object (default is false)
);
```

with the addition of the line:

```
$message->render();
```

doesn't work. What am i missing?

Comment: Additional info: I created the $message like recommended in the Typo3 documentary and then var_dumped "$message->render()" and the message could be seen in the var_dumped state. So basically it seems not to work from within the hook to be displayed in the BE. At least that's my theory. Or maybe i'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the FlashMessage to the message queue?

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageService;

// ... omitted some use statements


$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);

//...

$flashMessageService = $this->objectManager->get(lashMessageService::class);
$messageQueue = $flashMessageService->getMessageQueueByIdentifier();
$messageQueue->addMessage($message);
```

You wouldn't need that part, if you used the flash messages in the Controller.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FlashMessages/Index.html